# user resources csh.login restrictions

Tags: shell-script, rhel, csh, etc

I need to fix a vulnerability in a RedHat 6 server:

File `/etc/csh.login` must exist, and must trigger an invocation of source `/etc/profile.d/IBMsinit.sh`.

I verified file `csh.login` is in `/etc`, but I don't know where to put the invocation in the `IBMSinit.sh`:

```
# /etc/csh.login

# System wide environment and startup programs, for login setup

if ( $?PATH ) then
   #do not override user specified PATH
else
  if ( $uid == 0 ) then
     setenv PATH 
"/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
 else
    setenv PATH 
"/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin"
  endif
endif

setenv HOSTNAME `/bin/hostname`
set history=1000

if ( -d /etc/profile.d ) then
       set nonomatch
       foreach i ( /etc/profile.d/*.csh )
            if ( -r "$i" ) then
                        if ($?prompt) then
                              source "$i"
                        else
                              source "$i" >& /dev/null
                        endif
            endif
    end
    unset i nonomatch
endif
```

Comment: do you have an online reference to this requirement? Otherwise I'm tempted to say "just add it at the end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments by @steeldriver the bottom portion of the `/etc/csh.login` script is as follows:

```
....
       foreach i ( /etc/profile.d/*.csh )
            if ( -r "$i" ) then
                        if ($?prompt) then
                              source "$i"
                        else
                              source "$i" >& /dev/null
                        endif
            endif
    end
    unset i nonomatch
endif
```

That `foreach` loop is only processing files from `/etc/profile.d/` that match the pattern `*.csh`. So you'd just need to rename `/etc/profile.d/IBMsinit.sh` to this: `/etc/profile.d/IBMsinit.csh`.

Once you do that, the `csh.login` script will source all the `*.csh` files from `/etc/profile.d` and you should be set.

If you look in the `/etc/profile.d` directory, on most systems it contains both `*.sh` and `*.csh` files. The `*.sh` files are meant for Bourne & ZSH shells, while the `*.csh` files are meant for CSH & TCSH.